# PHP datetime format String to parse format '2015-09-24T07:46:13.722Z'

Tags: php, datetime

I'm searching for the datetime format string to parse this format:

```
2015-09-24T07:46:13.722Z
```

I have tried:

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TG:i:suT', '2015-09-24T07:46:13.722Z'));

var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::W3C, '2015-09-24T07:46:13.722Z'));
```

Both return `false` what is the stupid little error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using DateTime()

We can rewrite the above code using DateTime() as so:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-09-24T07:46:13.722Z');
$new_date_format = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strtotime()` with `date()` like this

```
$a = "2015-09-24T07:46:13.722Z";
echo date("Y-m-d\TG:i:suT",strtotime($a));
// output is
//2015-09-24T9:46:13000000CEST
```

for further info check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)